# Google Maps Zoom Level and map type not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Not sure what's wrong here. The map loads well and adds the custom marker, but zoom level isn't working, nor is map type.

```
<div id="locationMap" class="locationMap"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
         var map = null;
         var map_bounds = null;
         var gMarkers = [];

         function initialize() {

             var mapOptions = {
                 zoom: 12,
                 scrollwheel: false,
                 mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
             };

             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('locationMap'), mapOptions);
         }

         function addToMap(location, lat, long, title, marker) {

             if (lat != null && long != null) {

                 var iconBase = 'map-marker.png'

                 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     map: map,
                     position: myLatLng,
                     title: title,
                     icon: iconBase
                 });

                 if (map_bounds == null) { map_bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); }
                 map_bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
                 map.fitBounds(map_bounds);

                 // Create info window object
                 var wname = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                     content: location
                 });
                 gMarkers.push(marker); // Add To Marker Array
                 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                   //map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                   wname.open(map, marker);
                 });
             }
         }
     initialize();
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">addToMap('<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="locationMapPop"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br /><?php echo $profileStreet; ?><br /><?php echo $profileAddrLine2; ?><br /><?php echo $profilePhoneTakeOut; ?>', '<?php echo $profileLatitude; ?>', '<?php echo $profileLongitude; ?>','<?php echo $profileAddress; ?>', '<?php echo $map_marker; ?>');</script>
```

For some reason, no matter what number I add, the zoom level doesn't change on the map.

Comment: Please include all relevant code here, not on external pages.

Comment: Two issues, remove the `map.fitBounds` if you don't want the bounds to change, and the map has two mandatory parameters (center and zoom), you need to provide both.  The posted code never calls `addToMap`, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `addToMap` method `fitsBounds` on a single point when it's executed. No matter what your map is initialized at (e.g. zoom 12), `addToMap` immediately zooms it in as close as possible via these lines:

```
         if (map_bounds == null) { map_bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); }
         map_bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
         map.fitBounds(map_bounds);
```

Also, don't use strings (like `hybrid`) to specify `mapTypeId` (although it should still be working). Google's API explicitly provides (and tells you to use) their **constants**:

```
google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
```